# Entity field nullable=true but can not be null. (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, null, doctrine

I have some entities and when I find an interaction (CRUD) for each of them I stock the action in a Logs entity.
My Logs entity has FK to some other entities, and these FK fields can be null.
When I create my new Logs it says:

> Expected type 'App\Entity\Client'. Found 'null'.

For the precision, everything works perfectly without the Logs part so I need to fix it to have the result I want.

My Logs entity on where I get the error:

```
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'logs', cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL')]
    private ?Client $client = null;
```

My Client entity:

```
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'client', targetEntity: Logs::class, orphanRemoval:false, cascade: ['persist'])]
    private Collection $logs;
```

PS: I want the logs to not be deleted in cascade while deleting the stuff it refers to.

EDIT:

In my Group entity:

```
public function getClient(): ?Client
{
    return $this->client;
}
```

In my Client entity:

```
 /**
 * @return Collection<int, Group>
 */
public function getGroups(): Collection
{
    return $this->groups;
}
```

Here is where I get the error:

```
    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_user_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, UserRepository $userRepository, LogsRepository $logsRepository, GroupRepository $groupRepository, SiteRepository $siteRepository, ClientRepository $clientRepository): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('password')->getData()
                )
            );
            $userRepository->save($user, true);

            // take all needed information
            $now = new DateTime('now');
            $action = 'Create "'.$user->getMail().'" user';
            $result = 'SUCCESS';
            $gw_interaction = 'none';
            $client = $clientRepository->clientToCreateAndDelete($clientRepository);
            $group = $groupRepository->groupToCreateAndDelete($client, $groupRepository);
            $site = $siteRepository->siteToCreateAndDelete($group, $siteRepository);
            
            // write this action on the logs
            $logsRepository->createANewLog($now, $action, $result, $gw_interaction, $user, $client, $site);

            // delete the factice client
            // $groupRepository->remove($group, true);
            $clientRepository->remove($client, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('user/new.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

I can't put `null` as a value so I tried to create the needed entities, add the log and then remove the entities but it also doesn't work. It says I can't delete a parent row before children's (I have a group a child of a client) But if I delete the group and then delete the client, I still have this error. This is why I just want to be able to give a `null` at the beginning so I do not need to create and delete useless entities.

My function looks like this:

```
public function createANewLog(DateTime $now, String $action, String $result, String $gw_interaction, User $user)
{
    $logs = new Logs();

    $logs->setDatetime($now);
    $logs->setAction($action);
    $logs->setResultat($result);
    $logs->setGwInteraction($gw_interaction);
    $logs->setHisUser($user);

    $this->save($logs, true);
}
```

One possible solution:

Because I cannot solve this I found another way to save my values. Now, I deleted client and site columns in Logs:

> -> when I need them to be null I just do nothing.
>
> -> when I need them to have a value, I wrote the values in the action:
>
> -> before action had for example: "Create site siteName"
>
> -> now action is for example: "Create site siteName from group
> GroupName"

Comment: Can you show us your `$client` getter ?

Comment: I don't know if SO alert you of new answers if you commented so I answer here to inform you :)

Comment: You can just @username to notify someone about an update, you should update the post with the information you put as answer and delete the answer, it'll be way more clear. Imagine having a few responses with upvotes, you answer would be way down with more information on the question, it's not a good practice. 
That been said, could you add (as an edit) where the error is being thrown? Looks more like a controller problem than an entity problem, but it's hard to tell as it is.

Comment: Ok TY @Maniax I'm going to update my post :)

Comment: Way better :) So the function createANewLog is throwing the error? Do you accept null for the client parameter there?

Comment: There is the problem, I want him to accept it but he only takes entity type, that is why I created a client a group and a site ...

Comment: Could you show the code of createANewLog() ? Unless it's a third party method I don't see what's preventing you to allow null for client parameter

Comment: I added it, and a solution I have found to do it in another way

Comment: The definition and usage of the method doesn't match, there's no client in the definition. Anyway, glad you could find a suitable solution.

Comment: Oh... what a shame... yes that was the problem ^^
Thank you @Maniax ! :)